# How to properly export blender objects with children into unity

Tags: export, unity

I have a simple model with the top slide being the child. When I export this model into unity the parent transform is fine however the child transform has a negative rotation of 90 on the x axis.

[image: export settings]

[image: basic model]

[image: blender base model transform]

[image: blender child model transform]

[image: unity child slide transform. -90 on x axis]

Answer (score 1):

Untick 'Use Space Transform' and use '-Y Forward' and 'Z Up' in Blender FBX export settings:

[image: Blender Export Settings]

If you are also exporting Armatures, set the Primary Bone Axis to -Y and Secondary Bone Axis to -X:
[image: Blender Armature Export Settings]

In **Unity** use the **Bake Axis Conversion** import setting:
[image: Unity Import Settings]